# 12.10 - Can't connect to internet in software updater

Tags: update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

When I try the software updater, it tells me that it `Failed to download Repository Information` and I `should check my internet connection`. Of course my internet works. The error it reproduces is below

```
W:GPG error: http://www.duinsoft.nl debs Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E18CE6625CB26B26,
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/eugenesan/java/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found,
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/eugenesan/java/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found,
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generally means that there is no PPA for the current version of Ubuntu you are running (quantal).  if you go to http://ppa.launchpad.net/eugenesan/java/ubuntu/dists/ you will see PPAs for previous releases.

```
lucid/  19-Jan-2012 09:12   -
```

[DIR]   maverick/   19-Jan-2012 09:12   -
[DIR]   natty/  19-Jan-2012 09:12   -
[DIR]   oneiric/    18-Jan-2012 14:22   -
[DIR]   precise/    19-Jan-2012 09:12

So you need to wait until a quantal PPA is added.

Comment: Thanks. Going to the software update settings and turning off the java ppa updates solved the issue.